# nvd3 step line chart with identical size of horizontal pieces

Tags: nvd3.js

I'm in process of creation of the nvd3 line chart with "step-after" interpolation. I need to have these horizontal pieces to be the same size visually even in case if X axis values are very different (e.g. [0, 90, 100])

Here is something that I expect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjvDl.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the interpolate attribute of your chart.

```
chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                .margin({top: 50, right: 60, bottom: 30, left: 70})
                .interpolate("step-after")
```